# How to properly install certificate from sslforfree.com on tomcat server

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

Using https://www.sslforfree.com I have downloaded & unzipped getting 3 Files.
1) ca_bundle (Security Certificate)
2) certificate (Security Certificate)
3) private.key (KEY File)

I am unable to successfully put these files onto my tomcat server (running on windows 10)

What I have tried so far...
Created a Keystore :
1)  `keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore key_store_name.jks`

> Is CN=www.example.com, OU=example.com, O=example, C=US correct? [no]:  y

2)  `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias ca_bundle -file ca_bundle.crt -keystore key_store_name.jks`

3) `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias certificate -file certificate.crt -keystore key_store_name.jks`

I also get this error

> Warning:
>   The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore key_store_name.jks -destkeystore key_store_name.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".

Comment: Did you manage to make it work out?! I am with the same issue here